# Can't change sprite of sprite renderer through script or manually in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm making a 2d platformer game where at one point I have to change the sprite of the player and my code doesn't matter for this because I've stared at it for over an hour and there's nothing changing the sprite every frame or something else like that and I suspect it could be something wrong with the animator but manually if I try to change its sprite it doesn't work and if I change it before I play test it keeps the sprite I set it to and this is the player's animator keep in mind that the idle state has no animation attached to it [image]